# Can't Grant Users Update permission

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

There are several Active Directory user groups in my SQL Server database environment. I changed the users' permissions on all databases on the server. Several users wanted me to give them the update permission back. I used a command like this:

```
Grant Update To [DomainGroup\User]
```

But this did not work. Now no-one can update except me. How can I resolve this?

Here is the result of the query;

> principal_id  sid name    type    usage
>   35  0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3A43140000  NETONE\ibrahim.tackin   WINDOWS LOGIN   GRANT OR DENY
>   0   0x01050000000000090400000083741B006749C04BA943C02702F2A762  public  ROLE    GRANT OR DENY
>   5   0x010500000000000904000000FD051D9B2622FA4790703C7DB2C405A8  db_executor ROLE    GRANT OR DENY
>   6   0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3AF2380000  NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms   WINDOWS GROUP   GRANT OR DENY
>   7   0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3A5B2B0000  NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod   WINDOWS GROUP   GRANT OR DENY
>   28  0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3A292C0000  NETONE\SQLDDL   WINDOWS GROUP   GRANT OR DENY
>   32  0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3A352A0000  NETONE\SQLQRY   WINDOWS GROUP   GRANT OR DENY
>   33  0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3A5C410000  NETONE\SQLGelir-guvence WINDOWS GROUP   GRANT OR DENY
>   34  0x0105000000000005150000008D555C5A9C99DF04AB5BAB3A5D410000  NETONE\SQLGelir-guvence-mod WINDOWS GROUP   GRANT OR DENY
>   16384   0x01050000000000090400000000000000000000000000000000400000  db_owner    ROLE    GRANT OR DENY
>   16390   0x01050000000000090400000000000000000000000000000006400000  db_datareader   ROLE    GRANT OR DENY
>   16391   0x01050000000000090400000000000000000000000000000007400000  db_datawriter   ROLE    GRANT OR DENY

Comment: It think you should try `GRANTE UPDATE ON SCHEMA::Schema_Name to [DomainGroup\User]`

Comment: What should i write instead of schema? Is it db name?

Comment: Please update your question with the result of execute as user = 'DomainGroup\User';
select *
from sys.user_token;
revert; where DomainGroup\User is any of your problem users

Comment: So much sorry. I couldn't exactly get it. Can you explain it a little bit more? @sepupic

Comment: Your domain user may be a member of more win groups and db roles. To see where he could have a deny we need to explore all his membership. To do it you should impersonate this user and check its token. This can be done in SSMS by executing the code I posted above

Comment: For example, there is a user named NETONE\İbrahim.tackin. Will i replace the DomainGroup\User with it? So i mean, will my query be select * from sys.user_token; revert; where NETONE\İbrahim.tackin like this? And there is , in query?

Comment: execute as user = 'NETONE\İbrahim.tackin'; select * from sys.user_token; revert;

Comment: I updated my question with the result. It might be confused a little bit :/ Is it open to understand it? @sepupic

Comment: Your user is a member of db_owner so he has no need to be included in db_datareader, db_datawriter. But it is also a menber of some win groups that can have deny on update. I'll prepare a script to find out their deny

Comment: You are exactly rescuer ! Waiting for your script Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user that has access problems is the member of many `win groups`,
even if he's a member of `db_owner` he has limited access if someone `revoke`/`deny` some permissions to him or to his `group`.

To find out restrictions you should use this query:

```
execute as user = 'NETONE\İbrahim.tackin';   
select user_name(grantee_principal_id) as user_,
       permission_name,
       object_name(major_id) as obj_name,
       class_desc,
       state
from sys.database_permissions p
     join sys.user_token t
        on p.grantee_principal_id = t.principal_id
where state in ('D', 'R');
revert;
```

Here I limit the result to those `roles`/`win groups` of which problem user is a member of.

So your user has 3 `DENY` of `UPDATE` on all database:

```
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms UPDATE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\SQLDDL UPDATE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\SQLQRY UPDATE NULL DATABASE D
```

Your user will be unable to perform any `UPDATE` until you `revoke` these denies:

```
revoke update to [NETONE\İbrahim.tackin],[NETONE\SQLDDL],[NETONE\SQLQRY]
```

If you don't deny by error and the members of these 3 `groups` should not be able to `update`, you should exclude all your users that should be able to `update` from all these 3 groups.

Note you have same 3 `deny` to make a `delete`.

---

The `permissions` of any user is given by the "sum" of all the `permissions` that were granted/denied to him and his `groups`/`roles`.

Until your `user` is a member of `win group` that has `update` denied he will not be able to update. To make him  be able to update you should exclude him from `grous` with `deny` or `revoke` `deny` from these `groups`.

Comment: The result set is;

user_ permission_name obj_name class_desc
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms DELETE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms UPDATE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod CREATE TABLE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod DELETE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod UPDATE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\SQLDDL DELETE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\SQLDDL UPDATE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\SQLQRY DELETE NULL DATABASE
NETONE\SQLQRY UPDATE NULL DATABASE

Now, Where will i go from here?

Comment: I updated my answer by including state column in the query.Could you please include the column state in the result? Even if I think it's D. Win groups NETONE\SQLDDL and NETONE\SQLQRY have UPDATE denied, and the user himself

Comment: Yes @sepupic. Here is the new result set;


user_ permission_name obj_name class_desc state
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms DELETE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms UPDATE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod CREATE TABLE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod DELETE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\sql-ict-ad-rms-mod UPDATE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\SQLDDL DELETE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\SQLDDL UPDATE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\SQLQRY DELETE NULL DATABASE D
NETONE\SQLQRY UPDATE NULL DATABASE D

Comment: By the way, what is the meaning of D or R? Thank you deeply very much for you helps ..

Comment: D means deny. You have 3 explicit DENY on UPDATE. I'll update my answer now

Comment: Will i execute this query ? revoke update to [NETONE\İbrahim.tackin],[NETONE\SQLDDL],[NETONE\SQLQRY]

In SQLQRY account, there are many users who shouldn't have update and delete permissions. If i run the revoke query for SQLQRY, can they have update permission again?

Comment: I updated my answer. If only some users should perform update the only mode is to exclude them from these 3 win groups (at windows level)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @sepupic. Indeed, I am grateful for the Support,help. Is it possible to reach you via e-mail or here, if i have a problem during solution time? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes you can e-mail me, I just do not know if we can leave here our mails

Comment: I sent you email, you can also delete the comment with your mail